# Connect Android to laptop without Internet connection

Tags: android, windows, bluetooth

Say I have a laptop (Windows 10) and an Android phone.  The laptop does not have an internet connection and the Android does not have an internet connection.

I have an Xamarin app that uses a C# Web API that is deployed to the laptop (for testing).  How can I connect the mobile to the laptop without any form of internet connection? I believe I have two options:

```
1) USB cable
2) Bluetooth
```

I believe I have to install a wireless hotspot on the laptop and then a reverse tethering on the Android.

Have I understood this correctly? Do I have to do this regardless of whether I use a USB cable or a Bluetooth connection.

Comment: I think having both devices in the same network would be sufficient. So you could share internet from device (even though mobile data would be disabled) and connect to it from laptop

Comment: Of course you likely would struggle with firewall then

Comment: The point is that neither device is connected to a network.

Comment: At least in my phone theres no need to be connected to a network. Note that when a smartphone shares internet connection it uses mobile data (3G, 4G...) to be connected to the cloud. And Wifi interface to share it with any other device (e.g. a laptop). You could share it (nothing) just activating wifi tethering having mobile data disabled

Comment: Does that mean the phone can connect to the laptop to access the web api?

Comment: Yes, as your mobile would work as a router connecting them each other. Bus as I said, before that you likely should configure firewall on your laptop properly

Comment: Are you saying that if I have 4G enabled on my phone and Bluetooth enabled on both the phone and the laptop then I should be able to access the web api from the phone (remember there is no Ethernet or wifi involved).  Please assume that firewall and av are disabled.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195355/discussion-between-ruben-viguera-and-w0051977).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tethering is the name given to a mobile that acts as a hotspot. It make use of a network interface (Wifi, Bluetooth, USB port acting as Ethernet...) to share internet connection through the selected interface.

As you'll note I'm not incluiding mobile data in the list. Mobile data is used to connect to Internet. So your mobile is capable of connecting to internet via mobile data and share it via any other interface, i.e. Wifi, Bluetooth and USB (Ethernet)

At least in my mobile im able to just enable Tethering configuring it from Settings -> Wifi connections -> Share internet. Here I can switch on/off the desired interface: USB, bluetooth or Wifi. I can enable just one, both or even all of those

As far as I know a Xamarin app is an android app that embeddes a website and, optionaly but highly common, uses a server as an endpoint (your laptop in this case), also known as API.

So as you ask you don't want to have internet connectivity, all the connections must be made in a local network. To do so you could just enable tethering and turn off mobile data on your mobile. Then on your laptop, connect to your new network over wifi, enable ethernet or connect via bluetooth, depending on your choose.

Of course, you'll have to handle firewall on your laptop to ensure connections are made successfuly. But you should be able at last to ping each other.